# Generating Quarterly dates using moment().recur()

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-recur

I'm building a calendar application where users can save events that recur.

After a lot of research I've chosen to use the moment-recur plugin to the moment.js library to save the dates of recurring events in the database.

My issue is: users in my application will frequently wish to set an event to repeat at the end of a financial quarter.

In the UK these are 31st March, 30th June, 30th September and 31st December.

I can't work out a way to implement this functionality. If I set the recurrence to be '3 months' like this:

`let recurring = moment(date).recur().every(3, 'months');`

If the begin date is `31/03/2016` then it will skip June altogether as there are only 30 days in June.

If the begin date is `30/06/2016` then it won't work for the quarters that end on the 31st.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe generating 1st April, July, etc. and subtracting one day would be easier?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! That actually makes sense. In the end I decided to use the RRule.js package because it's more comprehensive than moment-recur but your solution would have worked!

Answer (score 2):

you can simply get the current quarter and by keep adding number of quarters like 1,2,3 you will get subsequent quarters.

```
moment().endOf('quarter').startOf('day');
moment().add(1, 'quarter').endOf('quarter').startOf('day');
moment().add(2, 'quarter').endOf('quarter').startOf('day');
moment().add(3, 'quarter').endOf('quarter').startOf('day');
```